# How to insert updated rows in a new table on DB2 - IBM

Tags: sql, db2

I need to create an update using sql dynamic  and all the updated rows have to be sent in a log table.
In microsoft, i can use OUTPUT clause and it inserts the updated rows in a table, but how can i do this in db2, using sql dynamic?

I have the following tables:

AllCustomers - contains all customers from a db

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Test |

gdpr_id. - contains all customers which should be updated

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

gdpr_log - should contain the output of the update stmt

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

I found the below syntax , but it just displays the results.

```
SELECT fields FROM FINAL TABLE
(update table set field = 'value' where id ='xyz')
```

I tried to create another dynamic stmt as

```
INSERT INTO 
SELECT fields FROM FINAL TABLE
(update table set field = 'value' where id ='xyz')
```

and the syntax is not recognized.
How can i replace it to insert all the updated values in a log table?

I have to use sql dynamic because the tables which need to be updated are stored in a metadata table and with a cursor, i create the update script for each line from the metadata table.

UPDATE:
Metadata table looks like this:

| table | column |
| --- | --- |
| AllCustom | Name |
| AllCustom | Lastname |

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test ()
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN

    --*****************VARIABLES *****************
    DECLARE EOF INT DEFAULT 0;
    declare v_table nvarchar(50);
    declare v_column nvarchar(50);
    declare v_rowid nvarchar(50);
    declare v_stmt nvarchar(8000);
    declare s1 statement;
    
    
    --*****************UPDATE STEP *****************
    -- Declare cursor
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH HOLD WITH RETURN FOR 
        SELECT table,column FROM metadata_tbl;
    declare c1 cursor for s1;
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET EOF = 1;
 
    OPEN cursor1; 
    
      WHILE EOF = 0 DO
        FETCH FROM cursor1 INTO v_table,v_column;
        
        
        SET v_stmt = 'WITH A AS
                            (
                              SELECT name
                              FROM FINAL TABLE
                              (
                                UPDATE ' || v_table || ' set ' || v_column || ' = ''some name'' where id in (select ID from gdpr_id )
                              )
                            )
                        SELECT COUNT (1) as tst
                            FROM FINAL TABLE
                            (
                              INSERT INTO GDPR_LOG (table,name, LOGDATE)
                              SELECT ''' || v_table || ''', name, current_timestamp from A
                            ) B';
                                    
            
        PREPARE s1 FROM v_stmt ;
        open c1 using v_table,v_column; 
        close c1;
                     
       END WHILE;
    CLOSE cursor1;              
     
END P1
```

Update step works fine, insert step duplicates the rows inserted.
What should I do to have the insert step ok?

Comment: Do you update all columns of all tables with the same string constant? Why to use such a complex statement at all, if you use procedure logic anyway? Isn't it really simpler to update a table with `v_table` name with one statement, and insert the corresponding row with another one?

Comment: I update specific columns from each table. I don't want to have a static update for each table because in the future, it is a big chance to add columns and tables to be updated. Having the metadata table and the cursor which creates the update, will be enough just to add the row in the metadata table, whiteout changing the entire sp. The update works fine and insert it seems to do what i need, but it duplicates the inserted row. I assume something is missing from the main cursor, the one which collects data from metadata table.

Comment: You haven't answered my 1-st question. You processes all metadata rows sequentially running distinct statements for each such a row. You have 2 rows for the same table in your example. It's obvious, that you run 2 different statements, 1 per each of 2 columns, which insert 2 identical rows into your log table (you don't use the column name in this insert). You might use distinct statements - UPDATE for all and MERGE for log. But not a single complex statement.

Comment: Moreover, your WHILE loop is buggy. You don't stop rows processing immediately after FETCH, when you get  NOT FOUND condition. It happens after the modification statement only. And you don't use parameter markers (`?` characters) in your statement, so use of USING clause in OPEN is not needed.

Comment: A table can have n columns and i update only 4 of them with the same stmt, for example. I tried to do it with 2 different stmt, but my issues is how to find the updated rows. Merge function is grouping all my updated rows in 1 unique row per table (exactly what i need), but how do i find the changed rows?

Comment: According to your `SELECT name FROM FINAL TABLE ...` you insert value of the same column `name` disregarding of `v_column` variable value. So, you may update whatever different column, but this SELECT returns a value for the `name` column every time. Is this really the desired result? If not, then please, explain the algorithm of the insertion logic into the log table.

Comment: You may try to create some complete reproducible example like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=ad30927052785607a8cb9dcd05f41bd5) one and say, what works unexpectedly.

Comment: Finished. I did like this: inserting the updated rows in gdpr_log table as they come from the update stmt; create a new insert stmt into gdpr_final_log by selecting rows from gdpr_log group by table name and the result is the one i need. Thank you a lot for your help and you input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use SELECT as an outermost statement and keep inner SELECTs in distinct CTEs, if you have a number of them.
Try this:

```
WITH A AS
(
  SELECT ID, NAME
  FROM FINAL TABLE
  (
    UPDATE GDPR
    SET NAME = 'Some name'
    WHERE ID = 1
  )
)
SELECT COUNT (1)
FROM FINAL TABLE
(
  INSERT INTO GDPR_LOG (ID, NAME)
  SELECT * FROM A
) B
```

**Update:**
Using dynamic SQL.
You must enclose the whole statement with some statement termination character (say, `@`) different from the default one (`;`) if you use some tool to run this compound statement and specify this statement terminator correctly there.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;
  
  PREPARE S1 FROM  
'
WITH A AS
(
  SELECT ID, NAME
  FROM FINAL TABLE
  (
    UPDATE GDPR
    SET NAME = ?
    WHERE ID = ?
  )
)
SELECT COUNT (1)
FROM FINAL TABLE
(
  INSERT INTO GDPR_LOG (ID, NAME)
  SELECT * FROM A
) B
';
  
  OPEN C1 USING 'Name', 1;
  CLOSE C1;
    
END
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, thank you for the idea. It works indeed, as a static sql, but I need to be able to run it using sql dynamic. So I created a sp, put it in a variable and it fails 'The statement named in the EXECUTE statement is not in a prepared state or is a SELECT or VALUES statement;, which is true , because stmt is a select.  How should I execute it?

Comment: @VeronicaP Look at the updated answer.

Comment: Hello @Mark, I need your help again, if it is possible. I need to do the same steps in Oracle. I posted the query, with the static statement (which works) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73124325/how-to-insert-updated-rows-in-a-new-table-on-oracle-sql-developer. My issue is that I don't find the correct syntax to transform the static stmt in a dynamic one. Please advise.